# Attribute one name for multiple columns with R

Tags: r

I have this : `data1`

```
       Aux     Cux
aa     3       3 
bbb    0       0
ccc    7.8     7.8
dddd   2.32    2.09
eee    5.68    5.45
```

and this, `data2`

```
       Aux     Cux
aa     6       6
bbb    0.3     0.4
ccc    7.5     2.9
dddd   2.09    1.48
eee    0.62    0.62
```

And I want this final data

```
          file1     |     file2      |
       Aux  |  Cux  |  Aux  |  Cux   |
aa     3    |  3    |  6    |  6     |
bbb    0    |  0    |  0.3  |  0.4   |
ccc    7.8  |  7.8  |  7.5  |  2.9   |
dddd   2.32 |  2.09 |  2.09 |  1.48  |
eee    5.68 |  5.45 |  0.62 |  0.62  |
```

I think, csv file will be saved like this

```
,file1,,file2,,
,Aux,Cux,Aux,Cux
aa,3,3,6,6
bbb,0,0,0.3,0.4
ccc,7.8,7.8,7.5,2.9
dddd,2.32,2.09,2.09,1.48
eee,5.68,5.45,0.62,0.62
```

how can I do it ? thank you

Comment: Have you tried `cbind` or `merge`?

Comment: -1 it is basics of R, try some manuals. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use `write.table` and pay attention to its `append` parameter.

Comment: How to give name to two columns ? and give another name to each of those two columns ?

Comment: You really have to show us what you've attempted. This is all really basic stuff, so it's unclear if you just haven't read the manual or you've tried something (which you haven't shown) and it's not working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data frames:

```
data1 <- read.table(text = "Aux     Cux
aa     3       3 
bbb    0       0
ccc    7.8     7.8
dddd   2.32    2.09
eee    5.68    5.45", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)

data2 <- read.table(text = "Aux     Cux
aa     6       6
bbb    0.3     0.4
ccc    7.5     2.9
dddd   2.09    1.48
eee    0.62    0.62", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```

Create a character matrix:

```
dat <- as.matrix(rbind(c(names(data1), names(data2)),
                       cbind(data1, data2)))
```

Set row and column names:

```
dimnames(dat) <- list(c("", rownames(data1)), c("file1", "", "file2", ""))
```

Write the table:

```
write.csv(dat, file = "filename.csv", quote = FALSE)
```

The resulting file:

```
,file1,,file2,
,Aux,Cux,Aux,Cux
aa,3,3,6,6
bbb,0,0,0.3,0.4
ccc,7.8,7.8,7.5,2.9
dddd,2.32,2.09,2.09,1.48
eee,5.68,5.45,0.62,0.62
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data3 = cbind(data1, data2)
header = matrix(c('file1','','file2',''), nrow=1)
write.table(header, "output.csv", sep=',', quote=F, col.names=F, row.names=F)
write.table(data3, "output.csv", append = T, row.names=F)
```

You may just need to play around with row.names to get that right.